# Finding a character type at a specific position of a Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Is there any way to, based on a regex string, return the type of a character in a specific position?

By example:

in regex: `[0-9]{2}/[A-Z]{2}/[0-9]{4}` have a total of 10 characters.

position 1 should return 'number'

position 4 should return 'letter'

position 3 or 6 should return 'symbol'

if the character is a symbol, I need to know what symbol it is, too.

Anyone can point me a direction to do this?

Comment: I just want check if the character is contained in one of this groups: number (0-9), letter (A-Z or a-z) or symbol (anything else).

Comment: So basically you want: 'letter,' 'number,' 'not letter or number'?

Comment: yes, and maybe another function to return the character in a specific position (in the case 'not letter or number').

Comment: This won't be possible unless your regex evaluates to a string with a fixed number of characters (which isn't very common or useful).  This would be impossible, for example, if your regex looks like this: `[0-9]+/[A-Z]+`.

Comment: @jahroy not my case. I am working only with regex which evaluate a string with a fixed number of character (like date or time, by example).

Comment: Well... If you're building the regex, you should know exactly what it contains.  If you're not building it, you'll have to resort to a different technique.  I'd recommend using the answer provided by @hwnd to capture the characters in question and then inspect them afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `typeof` operator in [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) that returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand. You can obviously use your existing Regex code along with your substring matching to pick out the specific position and do the comparison using the `typeof.`

```
alert(typeof 1);    //returns number
alert(typeof "a");  //returns string
```

Interestingly, for the case of symbols, you might have to use a bunch of logic statements to see and figure out, but I bet there is more caveats to it. The general technique would be to use a dictionary sort of a thing, and convert each letter to its UTF-8 encoding, and then take it from there. At the end, it would be a typeof "string". I am not sure if this is the most efficient technique.

[image]

If you just want 3 categories of checking:

**number, letter and symbol,** then it's fairly easy. It will distill to `if else if else` statements.

Answer (score 4):

> **With the logic of your question,** I just want to check if the character is contained in one of these groups: number (`0-9`), letter (`A-Z` or `a-z`) or `symbol`..

You may consider using a [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), adding `\W` which matches anything that is not a letter, number or underscore, and since `_` is considered a word character, you need to include that as well.

```
^[0-9]{2}[\W_][a-zA-Z]{2}[\W_][0-9]{4}$
```

---

> I need to know what symbol it is too..

In this case, if you want to see what symbol was matched you can place capturing groups `( )` at the position of where a symbol would be in your regular expression.

Example:

```
var str = '77$ba!1234';
    res = str.match(/^[0-9]{2}([\W_])[a-zA-Z]{2}([\W_])[0-9]{4}$/);

console.log(res[1] + ', ' + res[2]); //=> "$, !"
```

Comment: Wonder why he selected mine as the solution ..yours is elegant

Comment: Well maybe that's what he was looking for but didn't phrase his Q properly

Comment: The question is phrased horribly.  This answer contains the logic that should be used to solve the problem.  I'd recommend showing the OP how to use capturing groups to inspect the characters in question (but he'll probably never come back now that he selected an answer)...

Comment: I marked the answer from @hwnd because fits more easyly with my code. Maybe in the future (after I read the recomended article), I could rewrite my code based on this answer.